# Angular Merge few images

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, html5-canvas

Is there any option to merge few images together in angular. I saw one with an HTML 5 coding but  I couldn't get it to work

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  Image img1 = new Image();
  Image img2 = new Image();

  img1.onload = function () {
    canvas.width = img1.width;
    canvas.height = img1.height;
    img2.src = 'imgfile2.png';
  };
  img2.onload = function () {
    context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
    context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    context.globalAlpha = 0.5; //Remove if pngs have alpha
    context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
  };

  img1.src = 'imgfile1.png';

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make a function in an Angular component with that, and use a local variable to get your canvas.

```
@ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef;

mergeImages() {
  var canvas: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  let img1 = new Image();
  let img2 = new Image();

  img1.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = img1.width;
    canvas.height = img1.height;
    img2.src = 'imgfile2.png';
  };
  img2.onload = function() {
    context.globalAlpha = 1.0;
    context.drawImage(img1, 0, 0);
    context.globalAlpha = 0.5; //Remove if pngs have alpha
    context.drawImage(img2, 0, 0);
  };        

  img1.src = 'imgfile1.png';
}
```

In your HTML, remember to declare your local variable

```
<canvas #canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it didn't  seems to work. (webstorm) IDE giving errors in code

Comment: cannot find img1. then I added this variable   img1: HTMLImageElement;     and added img1 as "Image this.img1 = new Image();"  but then IIDE gives error "expected newline or semicolon"   near "Image".  I tried removing "Image" but then it didn't worked correctly.     I'm using angular Cli .

Comment: Yeah sorry I just copy pasted your code. I edited my answer, this should work.

Comment: Thank you  again for the help. now there's only one error  on "@ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef;"   it gives error under canvas.  error message is unused label.  I tried removing it but then it didn't worked.

Comment: Did you give a local variable to your canvas like I did with an hashtag ?

Comment: And did you declare all of those variables in a component ?

Comment: this is the only varible I declared   canvas: ElementRef;

Comment: All of this code is supposed to be in a component, you know that right ?

Comment: Then it should work ... **[this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzmhbg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)** proves it

Comment: oh now I see the problem. I  placed  "@ViewChild('canvas') canvas: ElementRef;"  above @Component. that's why I got that error.   Now It's working  thank you for the help.